# Как указать координаты gps в java

Tags: java, google-maps, gps

У меня есть код

```
 private void addProximityAlert() {
       double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeEditText.getText().toString());
       double longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeEditText.getText().toString());
       Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
       PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
       locationManager.addProximityAlert(
              latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
              longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
              POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
              PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no                           expiration
              proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
       );

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
       registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alert Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

В каком виде вводить информацию? Координаты и местность
Мои координаты: 54°51'30.8"N 69°09'00.9"E

Comment: в какое место вы тут хотите что-то "вводить"? И почему бы не спросить там, откуда этот код?

Comment: Нужно вводить в десятичных градусах смотрите https://datewiki.ru/wiki/Decimal_degrees